# ASP.NET Error when exporting report (Crystal Report to PDF)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm having this error when I want to export my Crystal Report to PDF into my local machine.

[image]

Based on my understanding, it says that the context is null. How would I trace where the values from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Tan. I do not know of a simple way of discovering which parameter is missing values when presented with this exception. Are you assigning parameter values programmatically or does your app prompt the user to provide them? If by code, could you provide us with a snippet showing how you do this? Are you supporting many reports? Is this the only one that fails this way?

Comment: Hi Zec, finally I found out that the problem is because I was passing in extra parameters than my values. I manage to get it fixed. Sorry but thank you so much for your time. I truly appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that appear to me as problem.

```
Response.Write("<script>")
Response.Write("window.open('" & ResolveUrl("~\Report\rptHandler.ashx?p=user_id|date&V=" & user_id & "&T=0&N=POrderProcessingCard.rpt&C=ORCL_PO") & "','_blank')")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

The solution is to check properly on the parameter and the value you are passing to. For example above, I calling 2 parameters (user_id and date) while I'm only passing 1 value to it. Therefore it will prompt such an error. Hope it helps :)